# Line 36 filename = title + '.mp3' . TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I created a Telegram bot that converts a YouTube video to the MP3 format and send it to the user. It was working great until I reinstalled python om my PC. After reinstalling I keep getting this error. Here is the code bellow.

```
import telebot
import youtube_dl
import re

Token = 'my token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(my token)

last_song = {'title':'', 'author': '', 'dir':''}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_message(message):
    name = message.chat.first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Hello, " + name + "! Please put the link of the video,  and I will" +
                     " return you mp3 file of that video! =)")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    url = message.text
    match = re.fullmatch(r'^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$', url)
    if match:
        options = {
        'format': 'bestaudio',
        'outtmpl': 'media/%(track)s.%(ext)s',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
            result = ydl.extract_info(url)
            print(result)
            title = result['track']
            filename =  title + '.mp3'
            last_song['title'] = title
            last_song['dir'] = '/media/'+filename


        bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio=open('media/'+filename, 'rb'))


    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Sorry, it seems that your url is not correct... Try again!")
                
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['title'])
    def start_message(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Title of the song is '+ last_song['title'])

bot.polling()
```

Comment: `title = result['track']` <-- this is `None` which makes `filename =  title + '.mp3'` hickup

Comment: try print(result['track']) before the error line , and tell us the output

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error message, in this line:

```
filename =  title + '.mp3'
```

title is `None`, and you cannot do `None + '.mp3'`.